# How to set preloaded video pic in cardview and onclicklistener to it?

Tags: android, webview, android-cardview, android-youtube-api

I have successfully loaded the video in the webview and it is playing also but i want to pass that link to other Activity which will play video using androidYouTubePlayer and also i want to display that webview like below.

problem:

1. how to display that video like below
2. how to set OnclickListner for it to pass the link to other activity.

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardViewDemo1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#00ff00"
                android:elevation="3dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: how to made that cardView appearence like above?

Comment: that can be a preloaded image try that load the image by using it's API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send your link to a new activity.

```
CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardViewDemo1);

    cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String linkVideo = "Here, you set this string with link your video ";

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            //HERE, YOU SET YOUR LINK VIDEO, INSIDE KEY "myKeyForReciveLinkVideo";
            bundle.putString("myKeyForReciveLinkVideo",linkVideo);

            //START YOUR ACTIVITY
            Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity,YourActivityGo.class);
           //Send your bundle containing the string with the url link to the new activity.
            startActivity(i,bundle);

        }
    });
```

To recover the data passed to your activity, within the activity.

```
    //Retrieve the arguments passed to new activity.

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(getArguments());

    //Use the key you previously defined in the bundle to retrieve the url link string.

    String urlLink = bundle.getString("myKeyForReciveLinkVideo");
```

I hope this helps you.